# How to use right versions of mongo, mongoid, bson, bson_ext with rails 4.2.4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, bson

I'm using rails 4.2.4

I'm trying to follow this tuto : http://robert-reiz.com/2012/03/05/rails-mongodb-tutorial/

in order to start using MongoDB with a rails application, but i'm having versions issues, here he's using some old versions,so when I 'bundle install' it says that it depends on an older version of activemodel (3.1)

I tried to use some other versions, fixing the conflicts one by one, but i ended up using mongo 2.1 (who depends on bson 3.0) and bson_ext 1.6.0 (who depends on bson 1.6.0)

How am I suppose to deal with this conflict? Is there a way to tell each gem to use a different version of bson?
Am I doing this all wrong?

Thank you !

Comment: What mondoDB version are you using?

Comment: I have the same problem :(

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Just running into this now...

Answer (score 4):

bson_ext is obsolete.   It's been merged in to the main bson gem.